# React: Update conditional on state change?

Tags: reactjs

I thought this would be a very basic feature for react, but it doesn't seem to update my code when variable state changes, for example if isPlaying changes, the icon doesn't.

Example:

```
<button id="playButton" onClick={this.onPlayButtonClicked} className="bg-green-500 p-2 px-4 text-white rounded shadow">
{ this.isPlaying ?
    <svg className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 9v6m4-6v6m7-3a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg> :
    <svg className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M14.752 11.168l-3.197-2.132A1 1 0 0010 9.87v4.263a1 1 0 001.555.832l3.197-2.132a1 1 0 000-1.664z"></path><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
}
</button>
```

onPlayButtonClicked definition:

```
onPlayButtonClicked = () => {
    if (!this.isPlaying) {
        this.start(0, Math.round(this.currentTime - 0.5));
        this.isPlaying = true;
    }
    else {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        this.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your isPlaying state changing? Can you check that in console?

Comment: Yes, it gets mutated inside onPlayButtonClicked, I'm logging it to the console to ensure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `isPlaying` to the state and use it by `this.state.isPlaying`.
The component will rerender when the state or props change.

Comment: Thanks! This worked when using state and `setState`, I'll accept it when I can.

Answer (score 0):

set state using `this.setState`

```
onPlayButtonClicked = () => {
    if (!this.state.isPlaying) {
        this.start(0, Math.round(this.currentTime - 0.5));
        this.setState({ isPlaying: true})
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ isPlaying: false})
        this.stop();
    }
}
```

or use the functional updater, if you have other state

```
   onPlayButtonClicked = () => {
        if (!this.state.isPlaying) {
            this.start(0, Math.round(this.currentTime - 0.5));
           this.setState((state, props) => ({ // get latest state and props
                   ...state, // included existing state
                  isPlaying: true //updated only what is needed
           }));
        }
        else {
             this.setState((state, props) => ({
                   ...state,
                  isPlaying: false
             }));
            this.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: HI, I have tried your code but no change. I have updated my question with onPlayButtonClicked function it this helps.

Comment: @AshSmith I updated the answer with a two possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

isPlaying is not state so it won't rerender and you won't see any change.
instead you can use state to handle it

sth like this :

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isPlaying:false};
  }

onPlayButtonClicked = () => {
    if (!this.state.isPlaying) {
        this.start(0, Math.round(this.currentTime - 0.5));
        this.setState({isPlaying : true});
    }
    else {
      this.setState({isPlaying : false});
        this.stop();
    }
}
```

and in jsx :

```
<button id="playButton" onClick={this.onPlayButtonClicked} className="bg-green-500 p-2 px-4 text-white rounded shadow">
{ this.state.isPlaying ?
    <svg className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 9v6m4-6v6m7-3a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg> :
    <svg className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M14.752 11.168l-3.197-2.132A1 1 0 0010 9.87v4.263a1 1 0 001.555.832l3.197-2.132a1 1 0 000-1.664z"></path><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the variable isPlaying in state variable. Like

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isPlaying: false
    }
  }
```

And then you can change the state by

```
this.setState({
   isPlaying:true
})
```

Then you can use this state in your code as

```
    { this.state.isPlaying ?
    <svg key={1} className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 9v6m4-6v6m7-3a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg> :
    <svg key={2} className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M14.752 11.168l-3.197-2.132A1 1 0 0010 9.87v4.263a1 1 0 001.555.832l3.197-2.132a1 1 0 000-1.664z"></path><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
}
```

This will re-render the component and your changes will be displayed.